# Ajax wont trigger in implementing a polling in Jquery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add a functionality that gets the real time total price using a polling technique and I already did some functions in the PHP side to retrieve tha latest values. My problem is I can't perform the ajax after the timeout. I don't know where's my error. Can you help me?

```
function getTotalContract() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('contracts/contracts/get_contract_total'); ?>",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: getTotalContract,
        timeout: 1000 //every second
    })
}
```

**here's the PHP side. I am using Codeigntier 3**

```
public function get_contract_total() {
    $json = array();
    $json['total'] = $this->Contracts_model->get_total_contract();
    json_header();
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I used this line `complete: getTotalContract, timeout: 1000 //every second` to reprocess the function. Is it wrong?

Comment: See [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) **timeout** part. That means how long the request will be watied or it returns error. You have to use `setInterval(function(){}, millisecond);` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timeout` is not a repeating timer...it is a setting to go into error callback if duration of request exceeds the timeout amount

if you want to repeat the ajax you need to use window timers like `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`

You could do something like:

```
function getTotalContract() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('contracts/contracts/get_contract_total'); ?>",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
             setTimeout(getTotalContract, 2000);
        },
        dataType: 'json'

    })
}
```

Comment: Ok I am following the sample tutorial about polling 
https://gist.github.com/jasdeepkhalsa/4353139

Comment: If you have time take a look in the tutorial maybe I did some mistake or the tutorial is wrong. :)

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks Ill try it. :)

Comment: They claim it creates open connection...there is no such thing with ajax

Comment: If you want an open connect use websockets

Comment: Yes, I am planning to use nodejs and socket.io but I am not permitted to install node on the server. That's why Im doing the polling method. :(

Comment: Can use ratchet for php

Comment: does it require nodejs for that?

Comment: One more thing if im using a polling method will my server crash or can be becomes slow? Example there's a multiple connection doing the same thing.

Comment: sockets are less server load. Need to ask yourself how important it is to have instant to instant updates also.

Comment: Thanks for so much information. Ill try to use ratchet and hopefully I can integrate it using Codeigntier. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you can do a normal ajax call to the url (without timeout)? Why don't you add the `error` method to see if the ajax call itself is returning an error.

```
function getTotalContract() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('contracts/contracts/get_contract_total'); ?>",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: getTotalContract,
        timeout: 1000 //every second
    })
}
```